# Warning message ("NAs introduced by coercion") when writing a tibble to a file

Tags: r, tidyverse, warnings

When I write a certain large tibble to a file using `write_csv(tibblename, "name.csv")`,
I get the following:

```
Warning message:                                                                                             
In vroom::vroom_write(x, file, delim = delim, col_names = col_names,  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

However, neither `tibblename` nor the resulting `"name.csv"` contain any `NA`s. So, how do I interpret the warning in such a case?

−−

As requested in the comments, this is the head of the data:

```
> head(b_r)
# A tibble: 6 × 13
  SCENARIO Date       Period `EU CPI` MSCI Worl…¹ MSCI …² MSCI E…³ MSCI W…⁴ Glbl G…⁵ EU IG …⁶ Glbl I…⁷ EU HY …⁸
     <dbl> <date>      <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1        1 2022-09-30      0  0.00708      0       0       0        0        0        0        0        0      
2        1 2022-10-31      1  0.00840     -0.0575 -0.0542  3.72e-3 -0.00360 -0.00600 -0.00284 -0.00150  0.0161 
3        1 2022-11-30      2  0.00595      0.0469  0.0451  2.10e-2  0.0545   0.00459  0.00716  0.0130   0.0209 
4        1 2022-12-31      3  0.00554     -0.0789 -0.0768 -4.33e-2 -0.0747   0.00629 -0.0105  -0.00557 -0.0158 
5        1 2023-01-31      4  0.00309      0.0265  0.0273  5.03e-2  0.0324   0.00950  0.00215  0.00623  0.00687
6        1 2023-02-28      5  0.00328     -0.0613 -0.0576  4.14e-4 -0.0440   0.00439 -0.0123  -0.0181  -0.0188 
# … with 1 more variable: `EMD HC Bd HDG` <dbl>, and abbreviated variable names ¹​`MSCI World`, ²​`MSCI ACWI`,
#   ³​`MSCI EM`, ⁴​`MSCI World SC`, ⁵​`Glbl Govt Bd HDG`, ⁶​`EU IG Corp Bd`, ⁷​`Glbl IG Corp Bd HDG`,
#   ⁸​`EU HY Corp Bd`
# ℹ Use `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Comment: Could you provide the head of the data?

Comment: could this be  a library conflict?

Comment: @Dr.Flow I don't know. I'm using tidyverse, lubridate, and scales. Nothing else.

Comment: @SantiagoGualchi Done that.

Comment: Maybe you could use some kind of flag for NAs, for example `na = "!@#$"` and see if you can find that string in the CSV.

Comment: try readr::write_csv()  readr is a part of the tidyverse. The error refers to vroom which is a different library

Comment: @Dr.Flow That gives me the exact same result (still mentions vroom).

Comment: @SantiagoGualchi There is no NA (or NaN) in the tibble or the file, with exception of the letters NA in the word SCENARIO.

Comment: Actually is vroom also a part of the tidyverse so maybe you should install the vroom library as well and try vroom::vroom_write(). Everything runs fine here, but there are several conflicts between the two libraries.